# Unable to install grub to software Raid array in Ubuntu

Tags: raid, software-raid, ubuntu-14.04, grub

How do you ensure Grub is properly installed on a software RAID array in Ubuntu?

I have a failed RAID array on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. When I first tried booting it, the Grub screen came up, but selecting any kernel resulted in an endless stream of system messages, and I never got to login prompt. Selecting a recovery kernel to boot, I was able to select the "enable networking" option, which mounted the array and gave me a login prompt, but now I'm trying to get it to boot normally.

Following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html) I ensured `mdadm` was configured correctly to use `BOOT_DEGRADED=true`. However, when I run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/md0
```

or:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/md1
```

I get the error:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may be missing from core image..
grub-install: error: unable to identify a filesystem in mduuid/ca0a39c0c1a9dada1aa912e49b297d06; safety check can't be performed.
```

Why is `grub-install` failing? Is this normal because one of the drives has failed, or is my RAID array misconfigured? How do I ensure it'll boot with just a single drive?

Comment: Did you found an solution for this?